# best practice for accessing data in a database while abstracting the accessing

Tags: java, android, database, design-patterns, android-contentprovider

I am attempting to learn the best practices for the following scenario.

**I have a defined set of data objects that are subject to change with updates. And some of these objects have arrays of other objects within them.**

Using `sqlite` I have the database set up with the following pattern: Each object is its on table. And if an object has a child object within it, it has a `fk` to the child table.

**The table names and objects are subject to change. So, to make it easy to change those, I need to be able to hide the database calls. I also need the ability to validate the data before inserting into the database. This validation also varies per object and can have different types of validation per object.**

Currently I am attempting to have a `DAO` for each object. And have a `DatabaseHelper` for each object that uses the `ContentProviders` to give access to the database. The developers then use the `DAO` to do their stuff.

It seems to be getting really ugly and complicated. It also seems like there would be an easier way... maybe some trick with `ContentProviders`.

So, is there anyway to integrate the `ContentProvider` into a `DAO` pattern better? Or is there a better way of accomplishing this goal?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: No matter what you do this will be a pain in the ass down the line :)

Answer (score 0):

I always have separate package names for database. I have written one separate Database class which I use in every project. I only change the database name, table name, column name. Following is the example class:

```
package com.mobisys.android.contactwidget.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class ContactDatabase {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contact.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String CONTACT_TABLE_NAME = "contact";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_ROW = "row";
    public static final String KEY_COL = "col";
    public static final String KEY_APP_WIDGET_ID = "app_widget_id";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER = "number";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT_EMAIL = "email";

    private final OpenHelper contactHelper;

    public ContactDatabase(Context context){
        contactHelper=new OpenHelper(context);
    }

    public long insert(String table, ContentValues values){
        return contactHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(table, null, values);
    }

    public long delete(String table, String where, String[] whereArgs){
        return contactHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete(table, where, whereArgs);
    }   

    public int update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs){
        return contactHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
    }

    public long countRows(String query){
        return DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(contactHelper.getReadableDatabase(), query, null);
    }

    public Cursor query(String table,String[] columns, String selection,String[] selectionArgs,String groupBy,String having,String orderBy){
        return contactHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
    }

    public void close(){
        contactHelper.close();
    }

    private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        OpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+
                CONTACT_TABLE_NAME+
                " ("+ KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                KEY_ROW+" INT, "+
                KEY_COL+" INT, "+
                KEY_APP_WIDGET_ID+" INT, "+
                KEY_CONTACT_IMAGE+" BLOB, "+
                KEY_CONTACT_NAME+" TEXT, "+
                KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER+" TEXT, "+
                KEY_CONTACT_EMAIL+" TEXT"+")");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
            String alter_query1="alter table "+CONTACT_TABLE_NAME+" RENAME TO temp1;";
            db.execSQL(alter_query1);

            onCreate(db);

            String insert_query1="insert into "+CONTACT_TABLE_NAME+" select * from temp1;";
            db.execSQL(insert_query1);

            String delete_query1="DROP TABLE temp1;";
            db.execSQL(delete_query1);
        }

    }
}
```

I also create one HelperDatabase class which have all database related static methods. Example class:

```
package com.mobisys.android.contactwidget.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;

import com.mobisys.android.contactwidget.data.CONTACT;

public class HelperDatabase {

    public static long inserContact(CONTACT contact, ContactDatabase database){
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactDatabase.KEY_APP_WIDGET_ID, contact.app_widget_id);
        values.put(ContactDatabase.KEY_ROW, contact.row);
        values.put(ContactDatabase.KEY_COL, contact.col);
        values.put(ContactDatabase.KEY_CONTACT_NAME, contact.name);
        values.put(ContactDatabase.KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER, contact.cotact_number);
        values.put(ContactDatabase.KEY_CONTACT_EMAIL, contact.email);
        values.put(ContactDatabase.KEY_CONTACT_IMAGE, contact.image);

        long id=database.insert(ContactDatabase.CONTACT_TABLE_NAME, values);
        return id;
    }

    public static void updateMyContactInfo(ContactDatabase contactdb, int _id, String number){
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactDatabase.KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER, number);
        contactdb.update(ContactDatabase.CONTACT_TABLE_NAME, values, "_id"+"="+_id, null);
    }

    public static Cursor getContacts(ContactDatabase contactdb, int sort){
        if(sort==1)
            return contactdb.query(ContactDatabase.CONTACT_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, ContactDatabase.KEY_CONTACT_NAME);
        else if(sort==2)
            return contactdb.query(ContactDatabase.CONTACT_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, ContactDatabase.KEY_CONTACT_EMAIL);
        else if(sort==3)
            return contactdb.query(ContactDatabase.CONTACT_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, ContactDatabase.KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER);

        return contactdb.query(ContactDatabase.CONTACT_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public static boolean isContactExist(ContactDatabase contactdb, String number){
        return contactdb.countRows("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+ContactDatabase.CONTACT_TABLE_NAME+" WHERE"+ ContactDatabase.KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER + "='"+number+"'")>0;
    }   
}
```

So, basically, i can have one class for each database in the project and one HelperDatabase class, which does all inserting, updating, retrieving and deleting functionality.

If my project relies heavily on a database, then it is good practice to have one static object for your database class which will open when your main activity will start and close when your main activity will destroy.

Following is code sample:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        HelperDatabase.contactdb=new ContactDatabase(this);
        startApplication();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        HelperDatabase.contactdb.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Hope, this will be helpful to you.

Comment: This is not using the `ContentProvider`. I am looking for a way to integrate the ContentProvider into the `DAO` pattern. This seems like a way to accomplish this goal, but i am really wanting to use the `ContentProvider` to actually make my database calls and still have a layer of abstraction similar to a `DAO` pattern. It seems like this would be the only way to truly accomplish my goal mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a data access layer in .net.  I created a BusinessObjectBase class as well as a BusinessObjectsBase (plural) class.  Moving common functionality into these classes was more challenging than one might initially suppose though.  Here are a few tips.

1) Since .Net is a typed language (and Java also), I needed to get type information about the derived class that the base class virtual functions were operating on.  In order to do this I used the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (though I actually hadn't heard of it until I realized its usefuleness on my own): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern

Basically, it's a generic class that takes its own type as the generic parameter.

2) I relied a lot on reflection.  I don't know how much java has to offer in the way of reflection though, or if it is fast enough to be useful for a data access layer.  I had to use a free fasterflect library I found on the net since the native reflection methods were too slow.

3) I used PostSharp (Java has Spring to do the same thing) to take care of change tracking so that it would only update objects if they had actually changed.

4) Okay, this is the most important part: Keep it simple.  In spite of the fact that I used a weird generic pattern, reflection, and aspect oriented programming to fully accomplish what I wanted, the heart of my dll was actually simpler than you might imagine.  I did lots of research to find the perfect orm tool, but found that in the end it wasn't difficult to just write some functions to dynamically generate my own sql statements.  This is where the reflection came in handy because I put attributes over the classes which represented tables in the database, and over the properties representing fields in the tables.  This way, you only have to change the attribute if the table or field name changes and...

5) I created a short app (almost fits on a single page) to read the database tables/fields and dynamically generate code files with classes for each table.

Okay, so you're probably not wanting to create something that complex, but I thought I'd put some ideas out there from my own experience and maybe you'll find one or more of them useful :)

(As a side note, I know a lot of people will be wondering: why did you go through all that trouble instead of just using an existing ORM.  I found existing ORM's to be overly cumbersome to use, and my implementation was more lightweight and faster than any ORM I've looked into)